# Why do I get an ValueError: Invalid padding bytes when I decrypt a string with an incorrect key using Python cryptography library?

Tags: python, cryptography

When I decrypt my string with the correct password following [this](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/#) simple guide on the library's website I get a correct string response.  When I change the final w to an e to get an invalid key, I get a padding bytes error like this stemming from:

> lib/python3.8/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/padding.py",
> line 101, in _byte_unpadding_check

Which is then followed by the cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken error I was expecting.

> ValueError: Invalid padding bytes.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken

I've read Stackoverflow and can only find one example of this but it didn't seem to apply when this is just the actual example from their site.

What am I missing?

```py
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
    
# print(Fernet.generate_key()) # used this to get the below
bytes_key = b'tsuG7oqhwyCsfUof35btDJA2eM7AdGf4tAM0o1zXOew='
    
# changed just one digit of key to test incorrect key
# bytes_key = b'tsuG7oqhwyCsfUof35btDJA2eM7AdGf4tAM0o1zXOee='
    
f = Fernet(bytes_key)
    
# encrypt a message
# token = f.encrypt(b"A really secret message. Not for prying eyes.")
# print(token) 
# b'gAAAAABiIOCx9Pp8HB9Asq0HUXb-t0SwX-W5ue7O3GJfuF9Rm4ue8I0Drk36NIyuZ0Mufknad5xkoL3091ZGOOS-QTqMbM-MeNrEC9jvmYx_Y0ojoSTaZWO9AXMJFZgdnvgPTB-wQIQd'
    
print(f.decrypt(b'gAAAAABiIOCx9Pp8HB9Asq0HUXb-t0SwX-W5ue7O3GJfuF9Rm4ue8I0Drk36NIyuZ0Mufknad5xkoL3091ZGOOS-QTqMbM-MeNrEC9jvmYx_Y0ojoSTaZWO9AXMJFZgdnvgPTB-wQIQd'))
print(f.decrypt(b'gAAAAABiIOCx9Pp8HB9Asq0HUXb-t0SwX-W5ue7O3GJfuF9Rm4ue8I0Drk36NIyuZ0Mufknad5xkoL3091ZGOOS-QTqMbM-MeNrEC9jvmYx_Y0ojoSTaZWO9AXMJFZgdnvgPTB-wQIQd').decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: `When I change the final w to an e I get a padding bytes error like this stemming from:` which is in the plaintext or in the ciphertext? In the latter, that is what is expected. Your post lack of information/code to decide..

Comment: The Fernet key consists of the concatenation of the 16 bytes signing key and the 16 bytes encryption key. Your change at the end changes the encryption key, resulting in incorrect decryption with wrong padding, and thus finally in the error message _ValueError: Invalid padding bytes_. Changing the signature key would accordingly generate an _InvalidSignature: Signature did not match digest_.

Comment: @kelalaka OK I have amended accordingly but the code was commented to explain the initially generated key vs my manual doctoring of the final letter.

Comment: @Topaco OK I tried using the correct key then changing the first digit and I get raise InvalidSignature("Signature did not match digest.") just like you say.  Interesting.  If you can post an answer to this affect and maybe explain why padding in this context does not mean padding to a length that would be helpful and I will mark as correct.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by _...explain why padding in this context does not mean padding to a length..._, so I described in my answer in more detail how the wrong key affects padding, and hope it answers your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Details about the structure of the Fernet key, the Fernet token and the algorithms involved can be found [here](https://github.com/fernet/spec/blob/master/Spec.md).

The Fernet key consists of the concatenation of a 16 bytes signing key and a 16 bytes encryption key, Base64url encoded.

For the posted *valid* Fernet key is:

```
Fernet key (Base64url): tsuG7oqhwyCsfUof35btDJA2eM7AdGf4tAM0o1zXOew=
Signing key (hex):      b6cb86ee8aa1c320ac7d4a1fdf96ed0c
Encryption key (hex):   903678cec07467f8b40334a35cd739ec
```

and for the posted *invalid* key:

```
Fernet key (Base64url): tsuG7oqhwyCsfUof35btDJA2eM7AdGf4tAM0o1zXOee=
Signing key (hex):      b6cb86ee8aa1c320ac7d4a1fdf96ed0c
Encryption key (hex):   903678cec07467f8b40334a35cd739e7
```

Note that both encryption keys differ in the last byte (`0xec` vs `0xe7`), i.e. your change has modified the encryption key!

The wrong key causes that the decryption generates a wrong plaintext with a wrong padding. *It is not the length of the padding that is wrong, but the values of the padding bytes themselves.*

Details: The plaintext used in the example:

```
A really secret message. Not for prying eyes.
```

consists of 45 bytes, i.e. the padding consists of 3 bytes, namely the byte sequence `0x030303`, since PKCS#7 padding is applied. For PKCS7# padding all padding bytes have the same value and this value corresponds to the number of padding bytes, for details see [PKCS#7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS#5_and_PKCS#7). If the ciphertext is decrypted with the wrong key, the last three bytes are `0x07e3f2`, which does not correspond to a valid PKCS#7 padding and generates the *ValueError: Invalid padding bytes error message*.
Note: If the padding is correct, it is automatically removed.

Similarly, an invalid signing key generates a corresponding error message *InvalidSignature: Signature did not match digest*.

---

The padding `0x07e3f2` can be determined as follows:

The structure of the token is: `version (1 byte) || timestamp (8 bytes) || IV (16 bytes) || ciphertext || HMAC (32 bytes`). Thus, from the token, the IV and ciphertext below can be derived:

```
IV:         f4fa7c1c1f40b2ad075176feb744b05f
ciphertext: e5b9b9eecedc625fb85f519b8b9ef08d03ae4dfa348cae67432e7e49da779c64a0bdf4f7564638e4be413a8c6ccf8c78
```

This allows decryption with AES/CBC *without* padding using the appropriate tools (e.g. [here](http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/)) and results in the following byte sequence for decryption with the *wrong* key:

```
6afb18a9791e407ce0eafd1d2c2ae1cef403e94903cf80e90193fafd0681e58f0e8fff0d3f3542901bced6fc8e07e3f2
```

with `0x07e3f2` as invalid padding bytes.

In contrast, if the correct key is supplied for decryption, the result is:

```
41207265616c6c7920736563726574206d6573736167652e204e6f7420666f7220707279696e6720657965732e030303
```

with the correct padding `0x030303`.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for providing this answer.  It was super helpful to a better understanding of the errors.